# IF >50% of the specified columns are of a certain value, change them to NA

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

Here is my dataset:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(88,3,88,4,88),
                   y=c(4,NA,3,2,4),
                   z = c(88,NA,4,88,88),
                   w = c(4,88,2,3,4),
                   k = c(88,2,3,88,4),
                   a=c(4,5,3,5,6))
```

For columns x,y,z,w,k if >50% of these columns are 88 then I would like to change all those 88's to NA for that specific row. For instance, for row 1 since 3/5 are 88 all those 88's would get changed to NA. But for the other rows since <50% of the specified columns are 88,they would stay as 88. This is what I am hoping to get:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(NA,3,88,4,88),
                   y=c(4,NA,3,2,4),
                   z = c(NA,NA,4,88,88),
                   w = c(4,88,2,3,4),
                   k = c(NA,2,3,88,4),
                   a=c(4,5,3,5,6))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this about columns or rows?  Notice that row 1 has 6 values.  The value 88 only appears in 3 times in row 1, and so it should not be changed to NA because it does not occur more than 50% of the time.  Is this about the specific value 88?  Or do you want to change any value that occurs more than 50% of the time?

Comment: Hey its about rows, but my actual dataset has hundreds of columns so I would like to specify the columns to look at. So in this case I would like to look at columns x,y,z,w,k (5 columns) and b/c the first row has 88 3 times, its >50% so it would be NA. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, with `rowSums` and a selection:

```
cols <- c("x","y","z","w","k")
sel <- (rowSums(data[cols] == 88, na.rm=TRUE) / length(cols)) > 0.5
data[cols][sel,][data[cols][sel,] == 88] <- NA

#   x  y  z  w  k a
#1 NA  4 NA  4 NA 4
#2  3 NA NA 88  2 5
#3 88  3  4  2  3 3
#4  4  2 88  3 88 5
#5 88  4 88  4  4 6
```